# Laravel - Changing cookie domain without having to user to clear cookies

Tags: laravel, cookies

I am trying to change my cookie domain for sessions but I am finding I need to manually clear my cookies in my dev environment for it to work. I am imagining this would be the same behavior for all my users when I move this production, is there anything I can do so they don't have to clear the old cookies that had been placed on their system before my update?  Currently, login fails and its just a redirect loop to login.

Edit

For clarification, I am trying to make my cookies work through out all subdomains. when setting it to this, the user is forced to clear cookies, or else login fails with a redirect loop.

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'domain' => '.example.com'

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible. Sounds like it would be a major security flaw if you could change the domain for a stored cookie to whatever you want or access a stored cookie from a different domain in order to change it.

Comment: I am not asking to change the current cookie on the user's system, I am asking how can over ride their cookie and force them to over write it.